# rss feed giving error

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I am writing a rss feed with php and mysql using PDO to get the info from the data base but am getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected  (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /rss/rss.php on line 36
```

Line 36:

```
$data .= "<link>"'http://localhost/gmedia/video1.php?g=.$row['g_code'].'"</link>";   // line 36
```

Comment: `"<link>"'` no concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You do not escape your string right. Read http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/ for some tips.

**Right way:**

```
 $data .= "<link>http://localhost/gmedia/video1.php?g=".$row['g_code']."</link>";   // line 36
```